# Remove CardView's rounded corners

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-cardview

I have used card view inside `RecyclerView`'s ListItem Layout. I have used `card_view:cardCornerRadius` as 0dp in content card layout, but still my card is showing rounded corners.

I have to remove Rounded Corner's completely. But could find any more solutions for fixing it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: can u post the code where you are setting up adapter and layout manager for your recyclerview

Answer (score 9):

Apply `app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"` to your `CardView`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"/>
```

This layout results in this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove card_view:cardCornerRadius attribute from xml and try again. No need to assign it 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write card_view:cardCornerRadius,just remove it,If you are not getting any solution just put my code on Style and reference it on Cardview.

```
  <style name="CardViewStyle" parent="CardView">
 <item name="cardCornerRadius">0dp</item>
 <item name="cardElevation">0dp</item>
```